# Q: Odoo QWeb report page counter on page

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

**How can you display the page count outside the footer?**

Hey,

I'm building a report for a customer. All is fine except that he wants to display the page number on the page (near the address field) instead of the footer, which is not working at all.

As I understand this so far, the subst.js used in the report module is responsible for replacing the `page` and `topage` classes with the page numbers.

The subst.js is called in the report/minimal_layout template, if `subst is True`. The boolean value is set in the report.py in the `get_pdf` method for the header and footer to `True`, while it is false for the `reportcontent`. If I'm applying bad practice and edit the Odoo core and set `subst=True` for `reportcontent`, the report engine does not render the body part of the report anymore and returns undefined.

Did anyone found a suitable solution for this problem?

Comment: Does it possible to add you attempt you have tried with the code ? please try to add it with your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Simply put this snippet where you want to display page count.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Page:</li>
    <li><span class="page"/></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li><span class="topage"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="0"/>  <p> <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1"/><t t-esc="nbr_page"/> </p> </t>
```